# Why does the 4f lenses configuration decrease aberration?

Tags: optics, fourier-transform

In many publications/lectures it is said that the 4f lenses configuration is the preferred configuration for imaging. 
My question is why does this configuration in an imaging actually minimizes the aberration.

Comment: Hi. Please provide a direct link for "many publications."  Then before asking, please try to work thru a derivation, e.g.   as in  http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-71-optics-spring-2009/video-lectures/lecture-19-the-4f-system-binary-amplitude-pupil-masks/MIT2_71S09_lec19.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Two points from  a very practical point of view based on laser systems.

1. Imagine there is a small dust particle on an optical element in your path. Diffraction from that little particle will create a pattern that expands with the propagation along the path. If you insert a $4f$ system, you "cut out the propagation" on a distance of $4f$: the plane at a distance $f$ from the first lens is imaged $4f$ away. The diffraction of the dust particle does not expand at the output of the $4f$ system, limiting its effects on the transverse plane (so a better image quality).
2. If the direction of your beam fluctuates because of mechanical noise ("pointing stability"), its effect increases with propagation (if the angle fluctuates, so the longer the propagation the larger the fluctuations). The $4f$ system, cutting out $4f$ of propagation, helps in reducing the transverse fluctuations of the beam at its output.